# How to fix the issue in eclipse "cannot be resolved"?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an Android application. Yesterday I have changed my system. Now I am using Mac OS for development.

Just I copied the project from my previous System to current System. I have imported the Project in Eclipse.

The problem is; Now I am getting following issue.
`"org.apache.http.entity.mime cannot be resolved"`

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: There is no such class or package. Can you show us the statement at which the error occurs?

Comment: I think the required jar is missing.

Comment: import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody; these are imported classes. Issues is; "The import org.apache.http.entity.mime cannot be resolved"

Comment: I have imported the required jar files that previously i was using in different system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the required jar to your build path.Right click on your project in the `Package Explorer`,then select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path`, clicki on `Libraries`
 then click on  `Add JARs`. Now point your `required.jar` from the `Add JARs` dialog.